# Generate contingency tables with bi-variate normal distribution

Tags: r, categorical-data, contingency-tables

I want to generate r x c contingency tables using Bi-variate normal distribution. Most of the works deals with generating tables from multinomial distribution where the total frequency is fixed. Suppose if i want to generate r x c tables from Bi-variate normal, Is it necessary that r and c should be equal? If so, How to generate as contingency tables using R?

Comment: Please register &/or merge your accounts (you can find information on how to do 
this in the **My Account** section of our [help]), then you will be able to 
edit & comment on your own question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An $r \times c$ contingency table contains an ordered set of $rc$ count values, which are non-negative integers (i.e., whole numbers that are not negative).  The multinomial distribution is one way to generate these numbers.  Contrarily, the bivariate normal distribution gives an ordered pair of *real numbers*, which are not whole numbers and can also be negative.  These numbers are not suitable to go into a contingency table, so it is not clear what you mean when you say you want to "generate the contingency table" from this distribution.  Now, it is certainly possible to *transform* a set of bivariate real numbers into a set of count values, but there are an infinite number of ways of doing this.

Comment: You are correct. I want to transform a set of bivariate real numbers to count values. Could you suggest me what are the possible ways of transforming?

Comment: Please register &/or merge your accounts (you can find information on how to do 
this in the **My Account** section of our [help]), then you will be able to 
edit & comment on your own question.

Comment: @Ben: You are correct. I want to transform a set of bivariate real numbers to count values. Could you suggest me what are the possible ways of transforming?

Comment: There are an infinite number of ways of doing this.  An obvious way would be to partition the space $\mathbb{R}^2$ into four regions and then count the number of times your bivariate normal random variable falls into each region.  However, you should note that this is equivalent to using the multinomial distribution.

Comment: @ Ben: Thank you very much.